# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <br />

Tags: json, flutter

I get the following unhandled exception:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
>
> E/flutter ( 7717): < br />
>
> E/flutter ( 7717): ^

I think the JSON is invalid, but I don't know how to modify it. Can anyone help me?

```
String url ='http://192.168.0.177/proto/submit_wo.php';
  var res = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url),
  headers: {"Accept":"applicarion/json"},
  body:{
    "id": '3' ,
    "status_id": '1' ,
    "category_id": selectedCategory.toString() ,
    "title": titleController.text,
    "description": description,
  }
  );

  print(json.decode(res.body));
```

Answer (score 4):

Your client is expecting JSON but the server is returning HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Check status code from res:

```
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    print(json.decode(res.body));
  } else {
    print(res.statusCode);
  }
```

I suppose it's not OK.

Comment: the res.statusCode is 200, so what should i do next?

Comment: There is reason to believe that the server returns HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: just found , headers: {"Accept":"applicarion/json"} -> headers: {"Accept":"application/json"}, but the issue havent solved.

Comment: Most likely the problem lies between client and server. Try this [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download/) more convenient tool to interact with server.

Answer (score 1):

1-Sometimes it happens because you put a **white space or a symbol** before the API link so you have to remove it

2-make sure it returns a JSON format because sometimes you should use this

```
 headers: {"Accept":"application/json"}
```

3-you should use character dependency

Note: if you are parsing your JSON data this may make an error

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Uri.encodeFull(url)` use `Uri.parse(url)`.

That worked for me when I had the same issue.

Comment: Worked for me too.. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes " instead of single

{
    "id": "3" ,
    "status_id": "1" ,
    "category_id": "selectedCategory.toString()" ,
    "title": "titleController.text",
    "description": "description",
  }

You can try your json [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I was trying to get data form the baseurl, not from the baseurl/products.json. So in the end, it had returned me html type, not json type. Verify yours if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, I had to check if the data is null in PHP Api. If the incoming data eg - if (!Empty ($ order)) - is not null, let the condition work. This way my problem was solved.

```
$order = $db->select("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY orderId ASC");
$list = array ();
if(!empty($order) && $order->num_rows > 0) (
while($rowdata = $order->fetch_assoc()) (
//array_push($list, $rowdata);
$list[] = $rowdata;
}
}
$db->link->close();
header ('Content-Type: application / json; charset = utf-8');
echo json_encode ($list);
 
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check the result of the API, and If there is any notice or error in the result so then change your API accordingly and once check the database which you are using to get the data from.
This worked for me, Hope it helps